# Is it possible to override operators in C++? If the answer is yes, what's the scope?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, overriding, binary-operators

I tried to override the `-` operator but I get an error. How to solve the error, and what is it for?

```cpp
#pragma once

class Resurse
{
protected:
    unsigned int _cantitate;
public:
    Resurse() {}
    Resurse(unsigned int cantitate) :_cantitate(cantitate) {}
    ~Resurse() {}
    Resurse(Resurse&& r)
    {
        _cantitate = r._cantitate;
        r._cantitate = 0;
    }

    virtual Resurse* operator-(Resurse* r)
    {
        Resurse* result=new Resurse(this->_cantitate - r->_cantitate);
        return result;
    }

    unsigned int GetCantitate() { return _cantitate; }
};
```

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Resurse.h"

class Hrana:public Resurse
{
public:
    Hrana() {}
    Hrana(unsigned int cantitate) :Resurse(cantitate) {}
    ~Hrana() {}
    Hrana(Hrana&& h) { _cantitate = h._cantitate; h._cantitate = 0; }

    Resurse* operator-(Resurse* r)
    {
        Resurse* result = new Hrana(this->_cantitate - r->GetCantitate());
        return result;
    }
};

void main()
{
    Resurse* hrana1 = new Hrana(20);
    Resurse* hrana2 = new Hrana(17);
    Resurse* result = hrana1 - hrana2;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Which `operator-`?  There are two:  negation (one parameter) and subtraction (two parameters).  The quantity of parameters depends on whether the function is free standing or not.

Comment: yes, minus operator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: thank you, but i tried to overRIDE not overLOAD

Comment: this is why I used pointers instead of const &

Comment: No, there's nothing here that requires pointers. This problem is called "useless use of pointers", and it is a common problem for people with Java background that are trying to learn C++. The problem is that C++ is not Java, and C++ objects work in fundamentally different ways. Nothing in the shown code needs to use pointers, and without pointers everything becomes ten times simpler.

Comment: *"but I get an error"* -- what is the error?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to overload (not override) operators.  However, the problem is, you are not doing it correctly.

You are trying to invoke `operator-` on `Resurce*` pointers, not on `Resurce` objects.  Your `operator-` needs to take a `Resurce` object **by value/reference** as input, not by pointer.  And return a new `Resurce` object **by value** on output, not by pointer.  See [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/)

And in your `main()`, you need to dereference the pointers before calling `operator-`.

Try this:

```cpp
Resurse operator-(const Resurse &r) const
{
    return Resurse(_cantitate - r._cantitate);
}
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    Resurse* hrana1 = new Resurse(20);
    Resurse* hrana2 = new Resurse(17);
    Resurse result = *hrana1 - *hrana2;
    std::system("pause");
    delete hrana2;
    delete hrana1;
}
```

Or, simply get rid of the pointers altogether, you don't really need them:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Resurse hrana1(20);
    Resurse hrana2(17);
    Resurse result = hrana1 - hrana2;
    std::system("pause");
}
```

---

UPDATE: I just realized that you are trying to implement a polymorphic `operator-`.  That is not going to work, mainly due to [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) on the return value, but also because you can't overload operators for pointers.

I would suggest using a separate virtual method instead of `operator-`, eg:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <memory>

class Resurse
{
protected:
    unsigned int _cantitate;
public:
    Resurse(unsigned int cantitate = 0) : _cantitate(cantitate) {}
    virtual ~Resurse() {}

    Resurse(const Resurse&) = default;
    Resurse(Resurse&& r)
    {
        _cantitate = r._cantitate;
        r._cantitate = 0;
    }

    virtual std::unique_ptr<Resurse> subtract(const Resurse &r) const
    {
        return std::make_unique<Resurse>(_cantitate - r.GetCantitate());
    }

    unsigned int GetCantitate() const { return _cantitate; }
};
```

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Resurse.h"
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>

class Hrana : public Resurse
{
public:
    Hrana(unsigned int cantitate = 0) : Resurse(cantitate) {}

    Hrana(const Hrana& h) = default;
    Hrana(Hrana&& h) : Resurse(std::move(h)) {}

    std::unique_ptr<Resurse> subtract(const Resurse &r) const override
    {
        return std::make_unique<Hrana>(_cantitate - r.GetCantitate());
    }
};

void main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Resurse> hrana1 = std::make_unique<Hrana>(20);
    std::unique_ptr<Resurse> hrana2 = std::make_unique<Hrana>(17);
    auto result = hrana1->subtract(*hrana2);
    std::system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Can you tell me the use or the scope of this example?

Comment: For me is mandatory , but I can't see the logic